# how to echo out or print the input during a bash loop against an array of IPs

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am running a loop like so:

```
for i in $(cat ips_uniq.txt)
do 
    whois $i | grep 'netname|country|org-name' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n//g'
done
```

Output:

```
netname:        NETPLUScountry:        INcountry:        INcountry:        IN

netname:        NETPLUScountry:        INcountry:        INcountry:        IN
```

This is good however my ips_uniq.txt contains over 300 uniq IP addresses so Ideally I want the IP address to be on the same line of each output.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I edited your question to put parts of it in code formatting.  And avoid having long single line code in your questions, it is harder to read.  You should take the [tour] and read [ask].  For your question, could you add a sample ips_uniq.txt file?  Is it one ip per line, no space, nothing else?

Comment: Testing your code, already I see something missingn in your `grep`.  I have to add options `-iE` for it to function how you intend it to.

Comment: Thanks very much, yes it is 1 ip per line and nothing else, like so:

8.8.8.8
8.8.1.1

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r i
do
    if [[ "$i" != "" ]]
    then
        results=$(whois "$i" | grep -iE 'netname|country|org-name' | tr '\n' ' ')
        echo "$i $results"
    fi
done < ips_uniq.txt
```

- using the `while read` method is a safe way to read files line per line, avoiding all problems with spaces or weird line formats.  Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for details.  Not required in your case, but a good construct to learn about.
- the `if` is to avoid empty lines.
- then store the result of the `whois | grep` combination in a variable.
- note that I replaced your `sed` with a simple `tr` which removes the `\n`, and adds a space to split fields.  Modify as required.
- then the final `echo` adds the IP address prefix to the results line.

I tested with ips_uniq.txt equal to

```
8.8.8.8

74.6.231.20
```

and the result is

```
8.8.8.8 NetName:        LVLT-ORG-8-8 Country:        US NetName:        LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8 Country:        US 
74.6.231.20 NetName:        INKTOMI-BLK-6 Country:        US
```

Using `printf` you could format the output to be better (i.e. fixed length columns for example).

Comment: Amazing thank you Nic3500 for the script - this works exactly how I need it to.